# What does mean Office.context.license in microsoft office.js

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

What is the meaning of **Office.context.license** property for outlook mail add-ins. it shows empty value for me.can it gives app license details ?[image]
i didn't find any definition on msdn  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161104.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Office.context.license is for internal use only by Microsoft. They are not useful for addin developers. Do you have any scenario that you want to use this for?

Comment: i wanted to retrieve licence details of app users. such as free, free trial, monthly subscription user...

Answer (score 0):

To get licensing details, you can retrieve the ?et= parameter from the url of your add-in.  ?et= will be there for paid or trial apps (and empty for free apps).  The value is the etoken.  This link has more details. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj164035.aspx